# QGIS - I cannot add attributes to a line segment

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, attribute-joins

I am trying to add the name of a polygon (an attribute called "member") that the line segment falls within, so that a field called member is added to the line file and it is filled with the member name.

Comment: Take a deep breath :) Try again, note exactly what tool you used and the parameters you specified and what exactly happened when you ran the tool, then edit your question, include that information and also include details about both line and polygon datasets, inc. spatial reference.

Answer (score 1):

Right click your line layer, `open attribute table` -> toggle editing ->`Open field calculator` -> In the expression tab put

```
CASE 
WHEN overlay_within('your_polygon_layer_name') THEN 'Your_polygon_layer_name' END
```

Don't write your polygon name, input it by clicking on the layer under the `Map layers` in the centre column of the field calculator.